# variation of parameters 1st order ODE Version

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

I have been given a variation of parameters formula for a first order ODE $x'(t) = a(t)x(t)+b(t)$ and have been asked to differentiate it, the formula is:
$$
x(t) = Ce^{\int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\,ds} 
        + \int_{t_0}^{t}b(u)e^{\int_{u}^{t}a(s)\,ds}\,du
$$

The solutions say that an intermediate step is:
$$
x'(t) = Ca(t)e^{\int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\,ds} + b(t) +\int_{t_0}^{t}b(u)a(t)e^{\int_{u}^{t}a(s)\,ds}\,du
$$

Would it be possible to explain this intermediate step to me?

Note by $x'(t)$ I mean the derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$.

Comment: Is the derivative of the first term clear? The second term differentiation is essentially by the product rule. Note that you can extract $$e^{\int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\,ds}$$ from the second integral so that the product structure becomes explicit.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! Yeah the first term is clear I didn't spot the trick to pull out the integral you mentioned. Thanks!